# porque al estar cerca de las coordenadas no hace nada? lua qbcore

Tags: script, lua

No sé que está mal aquí. Al ir a las coordenadas cercanas no hace nada, nop aparace texto ni nada. Se supone que al acercarse a las coordenadas debe salir un letrero diciendo q presione "e" para iniciar el trabajo, lo que pasa esq no sale nada y al darle a la e tampoco se marca nada (como esta reflejado en el código). Aquí las coordenadas no están puestas, pero en el código q está en el sv si q están. Si alguien pudiera ayudarme lo agradecería. Es un script para el job de repartidor, en lua para fivem (GTA V) qbcore, Gracias

```
--Empieza aquí
Citizen.CreateThread(function()
    while QBCore == nil do
        TriggerEvent("QBCore:getSharedObject", function(obj)  QBCore = obj end)
        Citizen.Wait(0)
    end

    while true do
        Citizen.Wait(0)
        local coords = QBCore.Functions.GetCoords(PlayerPedId())
        local distance = GetDistanceBetweenCoords(vector3(327.0, -242.63, 53.9), coords, true)
        if job == true then

            DrawMarker(1, vector3(327.0, -242.63, 53.9), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.0000, 0.6001,0,255,123, 200, 0, 0, 0, 0)
            if GetDistanceBetweenCoords(vector3(327.0, -242.63, 53.9), GetEntityCoords(PlayerPedId(), true)) < 10.0 then
                print ok
                drawTxt("Presiona ~g~E~s~ para empezar a ~r~trabajar", 2, 1, 0.5, 0.8, 0.6, 255, 255, 255, 255)
                if IsControlJustPressed(1, 38) then
                    job1 = true
                    QBCore.Game.SpawnVehicle("speedo4", vector3(x, y, z), heading, function(vehicle)
                        TaskWarpPedIntoVehicle(PlayerPedId(), vehicle, -1) 
                    end)
                    SetNewWaypoint(-292.45, 61.48)
                    QBCore:Notify("Vaya al punto indicado en el GPS para recoger las cajas")
                end
            end

end)
```

Comment: En vez de añadir spam, gástale tiempo a explicarle a los demás qué se supone que debe hacer en vez de no hacer nada. Si hay algún log de error. Algo que ayude a los demás a entender cuál es el problema. Puedes [edit] tu pregunta e intentarlo

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: @Alfabravo, ya está corregido, perdona no sabía el funcionamiento de esta plataforma. Si pudieras ayudarme lo agradecería mucho. Gracias de antemano, saludos.

Comment: @principiante Debes dar suficiente información para que podamos saber qué es lo que preguntas y qué puede estar pasando y, a ser posible, un código completo que podamos probar. No somos adivinos como para saber que la pregunta está relacionada con GTA y algún tipo de script lua que estás creando. ¿Qué es `drawTxt`? Tip: es más rápido si usas el cálculo de distancia entre vectores que la función `GetDistanceBetweenCoords` (mira la documentación de esta función).